# Android Emulator in Android Studio not displaying map on Extended Controls when simulating GPS location

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, location

I'm using Android Studio and have encountered an issue with the Android emulator. When I try to simulate a device's location/GPS in the Extended Controls, the map doesn't display. Instead, I just see a blank white screen. When I try to load "Routes", I get an endlessly loading message saying "Loading Saved Route."
It stopped working overnight.

Has anyone experienced this problem or have any idea how I might resolve it?

Thank you for everything!

[Image of White map Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf5q8.png)

I tried restoring the IDE, restarting the computer, updating packages in SDK Manager.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was solved by updating the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I solved it somehow. I'm not 100% sure that this was the cause of the problem, but it was resolved immediately after that.

I deleted all files from the path `"C:\Users\-username-\.android\avd"`. Then after creating a new device, the GPS simulation worked again.

Comment: Thanks. Creating the device emulated again it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

It's not needing to delete the emulator files in avd folder.

Just an Cold Boot of the AVD is enough.